# svn checkout/update to latest revision up until deadline

Tags: svn

**Scenario**: Students have access to a subfolder in an SVN repository where they will check in the solutions to their assignments.

The assignments have a fixed deadline (e.g. Tuesday, 12:00).

It is possible that students change the files after this deadline.

**Question**: Is there a convenient way to update my working copy to include all commits up to specified datetime?

**My approach**: So far, i looked at the log and figured out what the last commit before the deadline was. Then i remember that commit's revision number and update my working copy to that state with `svn up -rNNN`. But I'm sure there's a better way to do that.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{ DATE }` in your revision (`-r`). For example if you want status at `2017-11-06` date (today) you can use `svn update -r "{2017-11-06}"`. You can be more precise, see [Revision Specifiers/Revision Dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html):

```
$ svn update -r {2006-02-17}
$ svn update -r {15:30}
$ svn update -r {15:30:00.200000}
$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30"}
$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}
$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30}
$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30Z}
$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30-04:00}
$ svn update -r {20060217T1530}
$ svn update -r {20060217T1530Z}
$ svn update -r {20060217T1530-0500}
```

Comment: ah. i checked the man page and saw the date option, however I did not realise that this meant the whole datetime string. Thanks a lot.